# Coverting Hex to Image in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I am developing mobile app which talks with server via `PHP Webservice`. This is my first time using PHP. I managed to upload data in to database. Now i need to send an image to store it in ftp server. For that i converted `image->hex` and sent from my app.

**Server Side**

I got the hex code but not sure how to convert it in to an image and store in in ftp server. I am really struggling here. I googled it but couldn't find exact one.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `pack('H*', $hex)` to convert it back to binary data.
Honestly, base64 may have been a better route.  It's about 33% larger than binary, whereas hex is 100% larger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the HEX string to binary:

```
$binary = pack("H*", $hex);
```

[`pack("H*", ...)`](http://php.net/pack) is equivalent to [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/hex2bin), which is available since PHP 5.4.

Write it to disk:

```
file_put_contents("file.png", $binary);
```

Comment: It working like charm. But i am trying to store it in specific path like `file_put_contents("html\Report\Images\file.png", $binary);`. Am i correct

Comment: How to save image in that path? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have received a hex string in a page where you want to convert this hex to real image. Please check this code snippet will help you or not.

```
<?php  

    $hexpic=".......................
    .....................";

    # convert the hex string to binary

    $data = pack("H" . strlen($hexpic), $hexpic);

    #write the binary string into an image file

    file_put_contents("sample.png", $data);
?>
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I managed to store the image in ftp. Now i am trying to store it in specific path like `file_put_contents("html\Report\Images\file.png", $binary);`. but its not working. How to do that?

Comment: what is the server operating system you are using?