# convert binary data to image using php

Tags: php, binary, php-imagine

I have binary image data saved in my old database, it is saved by my old developer, now i want to display image from that using PHP, but I can not.

I have tried [`imagecreatefromstring`](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromstring) but it returns `FALSE`.

Binary example data: http://freezinfo.com/gg.php

Comment: That isn't binary, it is hex.

Comment: ok, but it's image data saved in database

Comment: May be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274691/coverting-hex-to-image-in-php  . And try finding the code from where image is getting saved in database if you have access to it.

Comment: it's given warning `Warning: pack() [function.pack]: Type H: illegal hex digit`

Comment: As the format is unknown, you need to contact the old developer and provide specification. Otherwise your question is only an invitation to place some guesses here. If you're really interested in an answer, provide an example code first that allows to reproduce your issue. Also add the specification. What tells the old developer of the materia? Your question in it's current form is just posting a (very) unspecific requirement you have. Just the *"but not working"* does not qualify as a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the string displayed as text ([extactly this sequence](https://gist.github.com/hakre/281cc062d52f13373f0d)), it's a lineup of hexadecimal numbers.

In Jpeg, the magic numbers of such a file are `FF D8` as the first two bytes and `FF D9` as the last two bytes (compare with [*How to identify contents of a byte[] is a jpeg?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4550296/367456)).

These hexadecimal (hex in short) numbers can be found at the beginning and end of your sequence as well:

```
FF00D800FF00 ... 1F00FF00D9000
##  ##               ##  ##
```

Looking for these magic numbers also reveals that the hex values are append with `00` always. It also shows that at the very end an extra single `0` is found.

So four characters always form one value. Hex-encoded this looks like 16 bit values however the value never goes over the 8 bit range (0-255), therefore there is always `00` visible.

With this information alone one then can try to turn this into a binary string that PHP's `imagecreatefromstring` can deal with:

```
$string = implode('',         // map array of binary strings to binary string
    array_map('chr',          // map ord integer value to character
        unpack('v*',          // unsigned short (always 16 bit, little endian byte order)
            pack("H*", $data) // hex to binary (high nibble first)
)));
```

Using such a string then in

```
$result = imagecreatefromstring($string);
imagejpeg($result, 'test.jpg');
```

reveals the following PHP error notice:

> imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: bad Huffman code

and the following image:

[image]

This looks desperately broken. So you are probably facing an additional encoding problem here. The last `NUL` byte suggests that more has been done and there also must be a reason why the data has been stored as 16 bit hex values instead of just binary data (blob) as databases have support for that.

But don't waste too much time, because of the flaw in the software and configuration that was used in the past, this might just be data-loss so all you can do is to restore from backups.

Answer (score 3):

The data you are trying to retrieve has HTML and its in HEX format but the image is corrupt or not valid.

**To get the data:**

```
// $url = "log.txt";
$url = "http://freezinfo.com/gg.php";

// Load Data from URL
$data = file_get_contents($url);
// Remove ALL HTML Tags
$data = strip_tags($data);
```

**The Errors**

Now Lets Examine the Header

```
 echo substr($data, 0, 4); // returns FF00
```

`FF00` is not a valid jpeg prefix It should start with `FFD8` OR `FfD9`

How did i know its a JPEG file and its not valid ?

```
 echo pack("H*", substr($data, 0, 60));
```

Output

```
����JFIF
```

It clearly has reference to  JFIF which is [JPEG File Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)

**How can it be fixed  ?**

A quick Image validation `imagecreatefromstring`

```
$data = pack("H*", $data); // Convert from hex
$im = @imagecreatefromstring($data);
var_dump($im); // returns false
```

Looking at the image header again `$data` .. i could see a pattern

```
FF00D800FF00E000000010004A00460049
  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
```

I noticed that `00` is been inserted so remove that would actually give us a valid image header `FFD8`

You can fix this with a simple loop

```
// Trim all Spaces
$data = trim($data);

$newData = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i += 4) {
    $newData .= $data{$i} . $data{$i + 1};
}

$newData = pack("H*", $newData);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($newData);
var_dump($im); // resource(6, gd)
```

Output

```
resource(6, gd)
```

**Conclusion**

You really need to examine the way you are converting your image to hex , it looks messed up form here

Comment: but, still it is not displaying the image. .where is fault?

Comment: ok..that's fine. thanks