# Is there equivalent for file_put_contents in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

can I ask , what is the equivalent for file_put_contents in javascript ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay for the node.js is there equivalent ?

Comment: for node.js you can use fs.writeFileSync - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In JavaScript? No.

In NodeJS? Yes, it's called [`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback). Here's the example in the documentation:

> ```
> fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
>   if (err) throw err;
>   console.log('It\'s saved!');
> });
> ```

Comment: is writeFile can be use like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274691/coverting-hex-to-image-in-php

Comment: @jemz: There's an example **right there in the documentation I linked**. I've copied it to the answer, but really, your best bet is to follow the link and read through the docs.

Comment: but it writing to a file , not writing the binary string into an image file

Comment: @jemz: The data can be whatever data you have, including binary data. Again: Read the documentation.

Comment: Crowder, my data is ascii I tried to convert but I cannot open the converted image

Comment: why the node.js did not list all supported encoding types ?

Comment: [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) can also [append to file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback).

Comment: @x-yuri: So can `writeFile`, I believe, if you set `flag` to `'a'`. (But I'd have to test to be sure, because characteristically the documention is incomplete.)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the reply above if you **don't want to overwrite the content of the file** but rather append to it

```
var fs = require('fs'); 

fs.writeFile(
    "foo.txt", // file
    "bar", // string
    {
        encoding: "utf8",
        flag: "a" // flag that specifies that it will append stuff
    },
    function(){ console.log("done!") }
)
```