# Convert string starting with 0x8950 to a valid PNG

Tags: php, png

I have a long string (60,000+ characters) that starts as follows ...

```
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844520 ....
```

I know that this string is a PNG, I can see the `magic number` on the PNG Wikipedia page is `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a` and this corresponds with the start of my string.

If I just write my entire string to a file I am unable to view the PNG. I know that I need to do something to the string before it becomes a valid PNG file. My issue is that I don't know the terminology for the format of the string as it is now and nor do I know the correct word to describe the format I am looking for. This is preventing me from doing any productive searching!

What's the name of the PHP function I need to run the string through before I can write to a `.png` file?

Comment: Maybe like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274691/coverting-hex-to-image-in-php

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anybody else, as the comments above say, the PHP function is `hex2bin`

Initially I was getting an error:

```
Warning: hex2bin(): Input string must be hexadecimal string
```

I then removed the first two characters from my string, `0x` and then the conversion worked perfectly:

```
$str = substr($str, 2);
$str = hex2bin($str);
```